# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

Trying to show my data in dropdown list its showing the `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type List<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>?` believe Its expecting `List<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>` but it getting `List<dynamic>` . What will be the syntax for this? I tried different different method, here its at least understandable by me.

My API function

```
    Future<List<Partner>> AllPathLab() async {
    var jsonResponse;
  
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://apiURLTYYYTY"),
          body: ({
            
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        jsonDecode(response.body);
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        print(jsonResponse);

        AllPathLabTestModel dataModel = allPathLabTestModelFromJson(response.body);
        print(dataModel.partner.length);
        for (final item in dataModel.partner) 
        print(item.partnerName);

        List<Partner> arrData = dataModel.partner; // this "partner" is actual json array of data[]
        return arrData;
      } else {
        print("Wrong URL");
        throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
      }
    
  }
```

Then try to display in DropdownMenuItem.

```
Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>(
                    future: AllPathLab(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState !=ConnectionState.done) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                      }

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return DropdownButton<Partner>(
                          dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                  underline: SizedBox(),
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: snapshot.data.map((Partner data) =>
                   DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                     child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                   value: data,
                   )
                    ).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value){

                    });
                        
                      }
                      return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

My model class

```
    class AllPathLabTestModel {
    AllPathLabTestModel({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.partner,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    List<Partner> partner;

    factory AllPathLabTestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AllPathLabTestModel(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        partner: List<Partner>.from(json["Partner"].map((x) => Partner.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Partner": List<dynamic>.from(partner.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Partner {
    Partner({
        required this.encPartnerId,
        required this.partnerName,
    });

    String encPartnerId;
    String partnerName;

    factory Partner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Partner(
        encPartnerId: json["EncPartnerId"],
        partnerName: json["PartnerName"] == null ? null : json["PartnerName"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "EncPartnerId": encPartnerId,
        "PartnerName": partnerName == null ? null : partnerName,
    };
}
```

Comment: tries to cast by making : DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                     child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                   value: data,
                   )
                    ).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>( )

Comment: Wow..Finally!!!  its working but after selecting item its not showing the selected item name. Why ? any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it's because you don't set a value... Here is how you should do it:    return DropdownButton<Partner>( value: _val,...
                    onChanged: (value){
setState({_val=value;})
                    });

Comment: So you have to create a variable that you pass to the Dropdown... here in my example I called it _val

Comment: Small error `Undefined name '_val'` Do I have to declare it after `class _MultipleTestBookingState extends State<MultipleTestBooking> {........`  I tried it also . Then it is also showing error like `is not Type of Partner `   [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/9dfbbc2d48eed6116e92851f26564277 ]

Comment: It is quite normal to declare beforehand _val : Partner _val;.... you can add it just below where you declared String encLabId = '';

Comment: https://gist.github.com/guyaristide/c1a2f5f03b966d9f4d50f66678633f7e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried removing future builder and tested it with dummy 
u need to create object to partner and in onChanged you need to set it to value

```
Partner partner;
List<Partner> pl = [
 Partner(encPartnerId: '1', partnerName: 'a'),
 Partner(encPartnerId: '2', partnerName: 'b')
];


//Dropdown
DropdownButton<Partner>(
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        isExpanded: true,
        value: partner,
        items: pl
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(
              (Partner data) => DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                value: data,
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            partner = value;
          });
        })
```

Comment: hi need your help i ve been banned from answering do upvote or accept it if it resolves your issue,Thanks

Comment: That's actually not helped me, but for someone who might get from local Json file might be helpful so Im accepting it... ;) Thanks for your precious time